# angular-google-maps updating marker model

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

Im using the angular-google-maps library but I cannot seem to get the map to update when I dynamically add new markers to my model. Hardcoded markers in the model are correctly displayed.

HTML

```
<ui-gmap-markers models="map.placeMarkers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" options="'options'" click="'onClicked'" modelsbyref="true"></ui-gmap-markers>
```

JS

```
$scope.map.placeMarkers = [
            {
                id: 1,
                latitude: 45,
                longitude: -74,
                options: {},
                title: 'Test 123'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                latitude: 15,
                longitude: 30,
                options: {},
                title: 'Test 1234'
            }
        ];
```

The above is working fine however when I do:

```
var place = {
   id: 3,
   latitude: 455,
   longitude: -574,
   options: {},
   title: 'Test 1233455'
};

$scope.map.placeMarkers.push(place);
```

The model is update but not the map. I have tried using $scope.$apply() but got an error since a digest cycle was already in progress.

Comment: Try the following link. It's a working example of adding marker dynamically using angular js. Follow the example, and hope it works for you :) [**LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/svigna/pc7Uu/)

Comment: I have the same issue, do you have a solution ? Ben_hawk

Comment: Yes, I haven't worked with this library for ages but if I recall correctly a performance change was made. You need to change the array reference in order for the map to refresh. Trying using angular copy on your places array and set the result on the map places property. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set modelsbyref to false in ui-gmap-markers directives

```
 <ui-gmap-markers models="places" coords="'self'" modelsbyref="false">  

   </ui-gmap-markers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same happened with me. Spent hours to find solutions.

It seemed like whenever we update markers angularjs doesn't update it immediately. just call **$scope.$digest()**  after pushing new marker to the array.

Also check **$scope.$apply()** function, it calls $scope.$digest() automatically.
Please refer to this tutorial which explain in detail:
[tutorial showing $scope.$digest(), $scope.$apply, $scope.watch](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html)

Its written in above tutorial:

> You may encounter some corner cases where AngularJS does not call the $digest() function for you. You will usually detect that by noticing that the data bindings do not upate the displayed values. In that case, call $scope.$digest() and it should work. Or, you can perhaps use $scope.$apply()