# angular-google-maps update model

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, model, angular-google-maps

How to update the model to load a new dataset of markers?

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" bounds="map.bounds" refresh="map.refresh">
<ui-gmap-markers
    models="dataset"
    coords="'self'"
    icon="'icon'"
    doCluster='10'
    click="onClick"
    >
        <ui-gmap-windows show="show">
            <div ng-non-bindable>
                <h3 class="gray3-text fz13 mbottom0">{{title}}</h3>
            </div>
        </ui-gmap-windows>
</ui-gmap-markers>
```

I am changing the dataset from outside the ui-gmap-google-map directive, like so

```
<p ng-click="changeDataset('allUsers')" class="cursor-pointer">
<p ng-click="changeDataset('allQuotations')" class="cursor-pointer">
```

the function is this:

```
scope.changeDataset = function(){
    switch (dataset) {
         case 'allResellers':
             scope.dataset = scope.allResellers;
             break;
          case 'allQuotations':
              scope.dataset = scope.allQuotations;
              break;

           case 'allUsers':
              scope.dataset = scope.allUsers;
              break;

           case 'allMarkers':
              scope.dataset = scope.allMarkers;
              break;
       }
 };
```

my scope.dataset changes but it doesn't update the markers in the map.

PS: modelsbyref="false" doesn't work.

Adding control="markerControl" to ui-gmap-google-map worked, but had to use this workaround:

```
angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('angular-google-map')).scope().markerControl.updateModels(newDataset);


<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" bounds="map.bounds">
<ui-gmap-markers
    models="dataset"
    coords="'self'"
    icon="'icon'"
    doCluster='10'
    click="onClick"
    control="markerControl"
    >
        <ui-gmap-windows show="show">
            <div ng-non-bindable>
                <h3 class="gray3-text fz13 mbottom0">{{title}}</h3>
            </div>
        </ui-gmap-windows>
</ui-gmap-markers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `changeDataset` function expects dataset name, after the following changes:

```
$scope.changeDataset = function(dataset) {
        switch (dataset) {
            case 'allResellers':
                $scope.dataset = $scope.allResellers;
                break;
            case 'allQuotations':
                $scope.dataset = $scope.allQuotations;
                break;

            case 'allUsers':
                $scope.dataset = $scope.allUsers;
                break;

            case 'allMarkers':
                $scope.dataset = $scope.allMarkers;
                break;
        }
    };
```

the map model is getting updated properly.

**Working example**

```js
angular.module('appMaps', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
    .controller('mapCtrl', function($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {

        $scope.dataset = [
            { id: 1, title: "Brisbane", latitude: -33.867396, longitude: 151.206854 },
            { id: 2, title: "Sydney", latitude: -27.46758, longitude: 153.027892 },
            { id: 3, title: "Perth", latitude: -31.953159, longitude: 115.849915 }
        ];

        $scope.allResellers = [];
        $scope.allQuotations = [
            { id: 1, title: "Q1", latitude: -31.867396, longitude: 144.206854 },
            { id: 2, title: "Q2", latitude: -28.46758, longitude: 152.027892 }
        ];
        $scope.allUsers = [
            { id: 1, title: "User1", latitude: -36.867396, longitude: 145.206854 },
            { id: 2, title: "User2", latitude: -33.46758, longitude: 142.027892 },
        ];
        $scope.allMarkers = [];



        uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {
            $scope.map = {
                center: { latitude: -30, longitude: 135.0 },
                zoom: 4,
                control: {},
                markerEvents: {
                    click: function(marker) {
                    }
                },
                options: $scope.mapOptions
            };
        });

        $scope.mapOptions = {};


        $scope.changeDataset = function(dataset) {
            switch (dataset) {
                case 'allResellers':
                    $scope.dataset = $scope.allResellers;
                    break;
                case 'allQuotations':
                    $scope.dataset = $scope.allQuotations;
                    break;

                case 'allUsers':
                    $scope.dataset = $scope.allUsers;
                    break;

                case 'allMarkers':
                    $scope.dataset = $scope.allMarkers;
                    break;
            }
        };




    });
```

```css
.angular-google-map-container { height: 480px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/nmccready/angular-simple-logger/master/dist/angular-simple-logger.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-google-maps/2.2.1/angular-google-maps.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="appMaps" ng-controller="mapCtrl">


    <p ng-click="changeDataset('allUsers')" class="cursor-pointer" >Display users</p>
    <p ng-click="changeDataset('allQuotations')" class="cursor-pointer" >Display quotations</p><br/>

    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" bounds="map.bounds" refresh="map.refresh">
        <ui-gmap-markers models="dataset" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" doCluster='10' click="onClick">
            <ui-gmap-windows show="show">
                <div ng-non-bindable>
                    <h3 class="gray3-text fz13 mbottom0">{{title}}</h3>
                </div>
            </ui-gmap-windows>
        </ui-gmap-markers>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem as in this question   [angular-google-maps updating marker model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344687/angular-google-maps-updating-marker-model/38092618#38092618)

It seems like whenever we update markers angularjs doesn't update it immediately. just call **$scope.$digest()**  after pushing new marker to the array.

Also check **$scope.$apply()** function, it calls $scope.$digest() automatically.
Please refer to this tutorial which explain in detail:
[tutorial showing $scope.$digest(), $scope.$apply, $scope.watch](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html)

Its written in above tutorial:

> You may encounter some corner cases where AngularJS does not call the $digest() function for you. You will usually detect that by noticing that the data bindings do not upate the displayed values. In that case, call $scope.$digest() and it should work. Or, you can perhaps use $scope.$apply()